# jQuery ajax post inside each function, success continue in each

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I have this simple jQuery `ajax` function, but it's inside `each` function because it's inside each post on site

```
$('.post .button').each(function() {
$(this).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'action/update.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          postID: $(this).closest('.container').find('.postID').val()
      },
      success: function() {
        $(this).css({'color' : 'green'});
      }
  });
});
```

});

But after success I want change some css of that element that has been clicked.
Basically I want to post this without need of refreshing the site using basic html post.
Is it even possible? Can you help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you may try this :

```js
$('.post .button').on('click',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action/update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            postID: $this.closest('.container').find('.postID').val()
        },
        success: function() {
          $this.css({'color' : 'green'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't work, I don't know why. Maybe when it succeed it like run that function anywhere outside that each function.

Comment: in this example we don't need any `$.each` function cause it will automatically set a `click` event for each ".post .button" element so when it's clicked we store the current element into `$this` then we can use it lated in `success` function. as a test can you set an attribute for each `.button` and then when it's clicked display that attribute to be sure that is the same `.button` you clicked. <br> you can check this simple example https://jsfiddle.net/358s9a6d/3/

Comment: oh yeah, you are right, I got that wrong. Yes that works, I'm high and mighty, thank you.